# Angular firebase 2 how to get all child details based on parent push key in child node?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

[image]

Hi, I am fairly new to firebase, I am trying to create a game scheduler application where I have two collections one for storing tournament details and another one for storing game details, each game has tournament id in it. I want to know how to find out all games by tournament id.

I checked firebase documentation but I failed to find correct document. Please point me to any documentation which talks about these kinds of scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store gameID inside the tournamentID. It would looke like this.

```
{
  "games": {
    "game01": {
      "team1": "X country",
      "team2": "Y country",
      "tournament": "tounament01"
    },
    "game02": {
      "team1": "X country",
      "team2": "Y country",
      "tournament": "tounament01"
    }
  },
  "tournaments": {
    "tournament01": {
      "tournamentName": "WorldCup",
      "sport": "cricket",
      "gameList": {
        "game01": {
          "gameid": "game01"
        },
        "game02": {
          "gameid": "game02"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps. Happy coding :D